# Line break on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, onkeydown

I have a textarea, and on each enter i want it to get blank if something has written. but my problem is; on the first enter it line breaks, and you continue to write from the second line. it only happens at the first enter. there is no problem with emptying the textarea, you just continue to write from the second line, which is the problem.

```
onkeydown= if(event.keyCode == 13){

    sendMessage();
}

function sendMessage(user){

    var message = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    sendMessage();
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

`keydown` happens before the character is entered in the `textarea`, so you just have to call [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) on the event so it doesn't enter a line break after you've called your function that clears the text-area. `return false` alone should be enough too if the code above is inline in the HTML, which isn't really recommended. See updated solution below:

---

For unobtrusiveness and back-compat, I'd recommend doing it all with jQuery:

```
$('#textarea_ID').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var message = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
        //rest of your function using `message` here
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8VQw/1/)

Comment: Note that the code at the top (not using jQuery) won't work in old versions of IE (8 and lower). The jQuery code at the bottom is a good solution though :)

Comment: @NicoBurns Oh yes I'll add a compatibility note. I guess IE7 would throw an exception as `event.preventDefault` is not defined before reaching the `return false`?

Comment: Added feature detection to the first code so it should work fine in all browsers. Still, upgrading to the 2nd solution is overall better in terms of structure/behaviour separation, back-compat and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery use the `which` property for the code. Then return false with `e.preventDefault();`

```
var field = $('.classname');

field.keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which==13){
        sendMessage();
        e.preventDefault();
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `return false;` to your `keydown` function. This prevents the default action of the key (a newline in this case) from being executed.

You may also want to include code to handle Internet Explorer's way of getting keycodes. Your new function would be:

```
onkeydown = function (e) {
    // Gets keycode cross browser
    e = window.event ? window.event : e;
    var keycode = e.keyCode !== null ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

    // Checks if it was the enter key that was pressed (enter = keycode 13)
    if (keycode === 13) {
        // Calls function to do stuff
        sendMessage();
        // Cancels the default action of the (enter) key
        return false;
    }
}
```